# turtlebot2 / kobuki base

Tags: imu, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to use turtlebot2 package ... with another robot. I'm experienced to use ROS (nodes, topics ...), to compile ...  and to use my robots with a previous version of ROS and I need now to use indigo with them, so to use turtlebot2 package and modify it. My problem is to find the way to do it, specially to find where are defined all the exchanges between hardware and nodes.

So I need to modify turtlebot2 package to be able to use my robot. So my questions are simple:

- where can I find information about type of exchanges between nodes and hardware (and in which node ?);
- I have no imu on my robot (but I have kinect). How can I find solution to use turtlebot2 package without it ?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222973/turtlebot2-/-kobuki-base/) by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-12-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkhansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25277/mkhansen/) on 2015-12-22**:
Do you have an existing turtlebot to run as a reference? If so, you could run the turtlebot and do an rqt_graph to see all the running nodes & nodelets, then use that as your reference guide for how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Turtlebot navigation package is based on the overall ROS navigation package, and I think that is what you really want. Read this page: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation and try tutorial #18. Make sure you have components for your sensors and actuators, you may have to write those yourself.

---

Originally posted by [mkhansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25277/mkhansen/) with karma: 156 on 2015-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0